# Crisp font lost, what controls the font in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I used to have my fonts in Windows 7 all pixel-crisp. Now suddenly they are blurry. I must have changed something, but not sure what..

And earlier fonts were always overridden. Specifying fonts for programs designed in Visual Studio would still be shown with the default crisp font.

Image here shows on top previous style, and below current (for same window).

[image]

1. How to revert back to my previous condition where all fonts defaulted to the crisp one?
2. What font is this crisp font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to remove the fuzziness so doesn't answer the questions directly!

Unselect the cleartype (which creates font smoothing which appears to be the issue here).

- Click Start Orb > right-click computer > click properties
- On the left pane click Advanced system settings
- Under performance click Settings
- UnCheck smooth edges of screen fonts
- Click OK > click OK

Change all my fonts sizes and types to tahoma and Trebuchet MS (XP style).

As to why, it could be the OS settings have changed, the GPU (graphics card) settings have changed...

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/fonts-in-windows-7-are-fuzzyblurry/0d76de45-0e87-4554-b14c-2aef6eb6ea29)

Comment: Worked! Though I think you meant "uncheck" smooth edges..